# Splitting a Google Sheet column to multiple ones on specific text in row

Tags: database, split, spreadsheet

I got stuck trying to solve this problem. I have multiple datasets which I paste into one column in Google Sheets and I would like to split it automatically to multiple columns based on a specific text (**textSplit**) using a function or script.

What the dataset looks like:

Data01 **textSplit** Data02
Data03
Data04
Data05
Data06 **textSplit** Data07
Data08
Data09
Data10 **textSplit** Data11
Data12

What I would like it to look like:

Data01 **textSplit** Data02 | Data06 **textSplit** Data07 | Data10 **textSplit** Data11
Data03                             | Data08                             | Data12
Data04                             | Data09                             |
Data05                             |                                          |

Amount of rows and splits varies so it would be preferable if the script/function could take that into account. Only part of text that is not changing is "**textSplit**". Length of text in line before "**textSplit**" string does not change.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.